# I want to make one database connection and use that statement and result for the rest of my program

Tags: java, database

```
import java.sql.*;
public static void cont(){
   try {

        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + "D:/BlueDb/db/db1.mdb");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

    } catch (Exception e)

    {

        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

`
so now whenever i call cont() i should be able to access the statement st and result rs

Comment: where is your query ?

Comment: i dont want a query in this function

Comment: Please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to solve the issue faced. Create a data access class with `Connection` object as an instance variable. Each time a query needs to be executed use the same connection object.

The `Statement` and `ResultSet` objects need to be closed after the query is run. One should not run two queries with a single open statement. Also, note the query method (`printAllRows`) uses try-with-resources statement used with the statement and result set creation. This allows the program close the two objects  automatically at the end of the query or when (in case) there is an exception.

One can create additional methods, similar to the query method, for inserting or updating the database tables.

The example code:

```
public class DataAccess {
    private Connection con;
    private static final String myTable = "MY_TABLE";
    public DataAccess()
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + 
                        "D:/BlueDb/db/db1.mdb");
    }
    public void closeDb()
            throws SQLException {
        con.close();
    }
    public void printAllRows()
            throws SQLException {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + myTable;
        try(Statement stmnt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sql)) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                int i = rs.getInt("id");
                String s = rs.getString("name");
                System.out.println(i + " :: " + s);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

This shows how one can create a connection to the database and use to access the table data. Additional calls to the database can be similar to that of the query method call. At the end of the application close the connection (this closes the database).

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
    db.printAllRows();
    db.closeDb();
}
```

Note, finally one has to catch the `SQLException` within the program code and handle it as per the application requirement.